# Can a vampire use its slam attack while full-handed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack, undead, two-weapon-fighting, natural-weapon

Suppose a vampire is two-weapon fighting. Does it have to drop a weapon to use its slam attack or can it use other body parts - kicking or elbow striking for example - to attack with a slam? I ask this because usually a creature must forgo one natural attack for each weapon clutched in a limb, but slam attacks are a little more nebulous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cannot make attacks with two weapons and slam as well with a vampire.

The rules are a little unclear what exactly constitutes a slam attack because it is the Natural Attack that is granted to [creatures](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/pudding-black/) with no appendages. However it also seems to be the Natural Attack granted to creatures with arms but not Claws.

This is supported by the [Natural Attacks](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Natural_Attacks) description which includes

> ...although often a creature must forgo one natural attack for each weapon clutched in that limb, be it a claw, tentacle, or **slam**).

Of course, they had to include that word "often" so you can rule that's not the case. I don't recommend using the Slam when you're also using multiple weapons, both for narrative and balance concerns.

Comment: "Slam" is the generic name for unarmed attack made by a non-human creature, it's "unarmed" for creatures. A Vampire's slam attack is from an undisclosed appendage. It's quite unclear as to how a Vampire slams.

Comment: I address that, yes. The implication of the rules about losing Natural Attacks to weapons is that if a creature has arm-like limbs, it uses them for its slam. The rules *don't* say you *can't* body-Slam or "headbutt" something. It's just strongly implied.

Comment: If you're trying to say something else, I would recommend creating a second answer. I don't agree that it's necessary to call it an "unarmed attack" because that has other implications and isn't (afaik) said explicitly in the rules

Comment: No, you can't body slam or headbutt because slam is an attack made with an appendage. It is not an unarmed attack, it's the equivalent of unarmed attack for creatures.